# How to make bolder underline text in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

After reading flutter documentation I got information about how to underline text.
But
My problem is, I needed a simple text style with bolder underline.

Comment: Yes I already read this,my problem is I need bolder underline with normal text style

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try adding the decoration in TextStyle.

```
Text(
  'Flutter Developer',
   style: TextStyle(          
     decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
     decorationThickness: 4,
   ),
 );
```

Answer (score 3):

Apply decorationThickness in a Text Style

The default decorationThickness is 1.0, which will use the font's base stroke thickness/width.

Text(
'This has a very BOLD strike through!',
style: TextStyle(
decoration: TextDecoration.lineThrough,
decorationThickness: 2.85,
),
)